# UI-Router - Dynamically showing and hiding elements based on state changes

Tags: angularjs

I am facing an issue where I am dynamically showing and hiding a button based on state changes, but for cases where the button should hide, I am observing a notable delay before the button gets hidden.

The button itself is set up as a directive as follows:

**Directive**

```
angular.module('app').directive('myActionButton', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'myActionButton.html',
    controller: function($scope, $rootScope, MyActionButton) {
      $scope.myActionButton = MyActionButton;
      return $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        return $scope.myActionButton.hide();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**Template**

```
<md-button ng-show="myActionButton.visible" class="md-fab md-fab-bottom-right" aria-label="Add" ng-click="myActionButton.mainAction($event)">
  <md-icon class="material-icons">add</md-icon>
</md-button>
```

**Service**

```
var MyActionButton;

MyActionButton = function() {
  var myActionButton;
  myActionButton = {};
  myActionButton.visible = false;
  myActionButton.mainAction = null;

  myActionButton.setMainAction = function(fn) {
    myActionButton.mainAction = fn;
    myActionButton.show();
  };

  myActionButton.clearMainAction = function() {
    myActionButton.mainAction = null;
    myActionButton.hide();
  };
  return myActionButton;
};

angular.module('app').service('MyActionButton', MyActionButton);
```

As you can see I am using a service for binding to in the directive's controller. I am also making use of this service from other controllers bound to views loaded by ui-router in my application.

On page controllers loaded by ui-router where I need the button to show, I inject my service and just call

```
MyActionButton.setMainAction(some function reference here)
```

This in turn calls show() in the service itself.

This all works fine, and the pages show the button when required. But for pages where the button does not need to show, I am not making any call on my service in the page controllers to hide the button.

Instead, I am listening to the $stateChangeStart event in my directive's controller and then calling my service's clearMainAction function.

For pages that don't need the button, this does work, but when transitioning from a page with the button showing, it takes a good few seconds to hide once the state change has completed.

Also, I should mention I am using angular material and their md-tabs configured with ui-sref properties on each of the tabs.

Can anyone shed any light on why I may be seeing a delay in the button hiding?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Here's a codepen based on the code I have shared - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpqLgL

When clicking from Tab 1 to 2 or 3, you will see the button momentarily shows and then hides after a short delay.

Comment: create a demo that replicates problem. Sure seems like the whole thing could be simplified. what determines criteria whether button is shown or not?

Comment: Sure, will get something together and update my OP. The button should toggle visibility based on having a mainAction set to a function reference - if that makes sense!

Comment: and what does `mainAction set to function reference` mean? WHat criteria determines that part?

Comment: Well for any of my pages that require the button to be made visible, their controllers just need the MyActionButton service injected and then a call made to setMainAction passing in a function declared in the page controller. So the button's ng-click will invoke which ever function that page needs it to. Anyway, probably best shown in a working example - I will knock something together soon.

Comment: See my codepen I have just added, I know the delay may not seem so bad, but if there are resolves in the state configs, then I think this will also delay the button in hiding.

Comment: add a `$timeout` in a resolve to test

Comment: I think the whole issue is due to `ng-show` css animations. If there are animations associated with class on that button `ng-animate` will manage the display stages and element won't hide instantly

Comment: Watch the button element iself in live html...can see those animation classes modify it during the `hide/show` timeframe. If you want instant action change the css animations or don't use ng-show and manage display yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to how `ngAnimate` integrates with core directives like `ng-show` when css transforms are applied to an element.

If `ngAmimate` detects css transform it will go through a sequence of adding/removing additional classes to allow the element to do whatever hide/show animations are set in css.

If you want the element to hide/show more abruptly you can modify the css for that element and adjust the timing or remove animation completely.

Alternatively you could not use `ng-show` and manage the display yourself either by toggling classes or by setting inline display style

Comment: That makes total sense, thank you very much. Will try out without using ng-show and let you know how I get on

Comment: was simpler in the days that animations were all done in script. took me a bit to figure it out too

Comment: Thanks again, this did the trick - updated codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaeNyJ?editors=101